# UILabel will not update to show fetched location coordinates

Tags: swift, core-location

So I'm just trying to do a simple test in Xcode, where the app will fetch the user's current location and display the coordinates on screen. This can then be updated by pressing a 'Fetch Location' button.

The app doesn't seem to be fetching any coordinates (the UILabel only ever displays default text).

It's just a single-page app. And yes, the @IBOutlet and @IBAction are correctly linked.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelLocation: UILabel!


    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var myPosition = CLLocationCoordinate2D()

    @IBAction func fetchLocation(_ sender: Any) {

        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!) {

        print("Got Location \(newLocation.coordinate.latitude), \(newLocation.coordinate.longitude)")

        myPosition = newLocation.coordinate

        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        labelLocation.text = "Got Location \(newLocation.coordinate.latitude), \(newLocation.coordinate.longitude)"

    }



}
```

Comment: 1. When you launch the app do you get any alerts for the app *asking* you to allow location tracking? 2. Have you enabled locationTracking from your Capabilities or plist? If not see [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started) and look for "Receiving Location Updates" 3. place a breakpoint on the first print and let us know if you're even getting there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:
Enable the `Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description` in your info.plist file

1. Go to your info.plist file
2. Click on + on Information property list and type Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description
3. In the value type why you want to request the users location (this will be shown to the user)

Step 2:
Get the location
Use this code:

```
guard let latitude = manager.location?.coordinate.latitude, let longitude = manager.location?.coordinate.longitude else { return }

locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
labelLocation.text = "Got Location \(latitude), \(longitude)"
```

Comment: I've already included the relevant keys in the info.plist file. Where should I be adding that code? It doesn't seem to change anything where I've put it in.

Comment: @joshlorschy, can you zip and send me your project and I´ll try to help you figure out your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think that you can resolve it adding the "Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description" key into Info.plist, this is an important step in Location topic.

Regards!